# Compare array value in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, arraylist

I need to compare array values,One array is taken from external user and the second array is fetch from mysql table.
The code is using is

```
<?php
include('db.php');
$input_array=array();
$input_array=explode("," , $_POST['list']);
print_r($input_array)."<br>";

$array                   = array();



                         $result =mysql_query("SELECT b_no FROM abc");
                         while($fetch_array=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                         $array[] = $fetch_array['b_no'];
                         }



                        echo count($array)."<br>";
                        echo count($input_array)."<br>";
                         ?>
```

For example user input is(explode array)

```
Array ( [0] => 627501 [1] => 627502 [2] => 627503 [3] => 627504 [4] => 627505 [5] => 627506 [6] => 627507 [7] => 627508 [8] => 627509 [9] => 627510 )
```

and 
suppose i have index value 8,1 and 9(twice) in mysql table data than output should be this

```
Array ( [0] => 627501 [1] => 627509 [2] => 627510 [3] => 627510)
```

i also wasted too much time on Array_intersect function.....how can its possible??
Thanks :)

Comment: 1) How do you want to compare them? 2) What do you want to do? Give us an [example!](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: can do with `in_array()` function

Comment: yes in_array() function is used

Comment: now it right..Thanks kindly suggest solution :(

Comment: What's the problem with array_intersect? array_intersect($array, $input_array) outputs what you desire (At least in the example above)

Comment: Array_intersect is working properly only when user input array has index approximately 10.Actually i have 11970 values in mysql table and input values more than 1000,Array_intersect not identify 627510 while this number is present in both arrays while index of input array is 100

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
<?php
include('db.php');
$input_array=array();
$input_array=explode("," , $_POST['list']);
print_r($input_array)."<br>";

$array                   = array();



                         $result =mysql_query("SELECT b_no FROM d200_62");
                         while($fetch_array=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                         $array[] = $fetch_array['b_no'];
                         }

                        for($j=0;$j<10;$j++){
                            for($j=0;$j<11970;$j++){
                                if($array[$j]=$input_array[$i]){
                                    echo $array[$j];

                                }

                        echo count($array)."<br>";
                        echo count($input_array)."<br>";
                         ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

well, maybe you can use this:

```
 $dbarray   = array('a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'a6');
 $userarray = array('a2', 'a3', 'a3', 'a6');

 $negativearray = array_diff($dbarray, $userarray);
 $positivearray = array_diff($dbarray, $negativearray);

 foreach($positivearray as $chunk){
  echo $chunk.' ['.count(preg_grep('/^'.$chunk.'$/', $userarray)).']<br>';
 }
```

Output:

```
a2 [1]
a3 [2]
a6 [1]
```